# ε-close to t-wise inependence of SPN (AES)

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, spn

According to [theorem 3.13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/507.pdf), the 6 rounds of AES is 0.472-close to pairwise independence. It is also mentioned  t-wise independence used to analyze higher order derivates attacks. it is also mentioned [3-wise indepdent  permutations have a potential application in strengthening short encryption keys](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-24654-1_17.pdf). My questions are related to the fundamentals of t-wise independence permutations.

**Q.1** What does it mean to have 2, 3 or 4-wise independence to a block cipher from a mathematical perspective?

**Q.2** what does it mean 6 rounds of AES is 0.472-close to pairwise independence?

**Q.3** (assumption) Does higher order independence have opposite relation with key size but same security level?

Comment: Q2: Definition 2.5 explains what it means to be $\delta$-close to t-wise independence. Q1: t-wise independence is Definition 2.5 with $\delta=0$

Comment: your questions are a bit vague and some answers are embedded in the definitions as in the comment by @Mikero. Also please help readability by stating at least one of these definitions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the definition but what implication does it have in term of AES security (number of rounds), secondly, for Q1, is there a relationship between k-wise and higher order derivatives (for example 2-wise means immune against second order differential cryptanlysis)